# How can I arrange proxies with tor in a specific order in proxychain?

Tags: configuration, onion-routing, proxy

I am aware that I can have the proxy list in order with "Dynamic chaining".  However I am not sure with the flow of the connections in relation with tor (like will proxy go first before tor or vice versa).
But my question is:

Is it possible to use proxychain in this order?

my pc - > proxy -> tor -> proxy -> destination

Which means my entry is in a proxy, then from the proxy to tor entry node, then from tor exit node to another proxy before reaching the destination? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is possible! Utilize the Stem library and `proxychains` to gain full control for connecting to a `separate` proxy instance after Tor, after that use the connection handle to make a proxified request via the last proxy in your schema

Comment: Does that mean that my connection will use the proxies in the proxychain app first then will enter tor using Stem library and will exit tor to enter the proxy from the exit node of tor still using the Stem library?

like:
(Proxychain: proxy1, proxy2) -> (Stem Library: (Entry Node to Exit Node -> proxy1, proxy 2)) -> The destination machine. Is that how it works?

Comment: Yes, it will be exactly how it works, your requests **after** the Tor exit you'll have to do yourself using the connection provided by Stem. It's one of the possible ways, actually. If you will describe your task/setup in deeper details I'll be able to give you more deep and precise instructions and explanations

Comment: I would like to use my computer with proxy chain, like two or three proxies before entering  tor using proxychain in terminal, then from tor entry to exit node it will enter in another 1 or 2 proxies before reaching the destination (just like what is described above).  So that I can browse the web or connect to ssh or telnet.  I'm just quite intimidated with Stem library because I'm still trying to learn programming basics

Comment: and I'm using a regular ubuntu based distro (It's not Kali just a day to day os)

Comment: Well, you need to construct the circuit **for Tor** first using the `proxychains` tool, then specify it as a proxy for tor - and it's better to be done via VM's. After that you're **not** using Stem - it's not for your case, you're just connecting through Tor to the proxies you wish to be *after* Tor you're constructing a pipe via using `proxychains` again with Tor proxy as a first one - and after that you will obtain a connection pipe you desire according the scenario you've described. For a perfect insulation use 3 VM's, and a third one will have the pipe you wish to have. Virtualbox is ok

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much for trying to help. It seems that the question I asked is too advance for me as of now. But I will get back on this when I have enough understanding on how these things work, thanks again